# Ajax method is not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I tried to get data from web method in asp page to ajax jquery method. But Ajax method is not firing. And not even showing any error message. Please help me

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Sample(string data)
{

    string strStatus = data+ "hello world";       
    return strStatus;

}
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
        var data = $("#<%=txtsample.ClientID%>").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Default2.aspx/Sample")%>',
            data: '{data:' + data + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#<%=lblMsg.ClientID%>").text(response.data);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                $("#<%=lblMsg.ClientID%>").text(response.data);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                $("#<%=lblMsg.ClientID%>").text(response.data);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: are you sure the url you entered is correct?                          url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Default2.aspx/Sample")%>', i guess you should have to change it to correct one like this url:'~/default2.aspx/sample' the iis don't care about uppercase lowercase isn't it fun? and if you cant succeed with webmethod try asmx webservices they have more fun

Comment: Do you have jQuery library loaded?

Comment: I used this one   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

you should **cancel** submit **click event** first using

```
e.preventDefault();
```

in beginning or

```
return false;
```

at the end of code;

Comment: I changed  data: '{data:' + data + '}', to  data: '{"data":"' + data+ '"}' . It works fine. Thank you all for all your responses

Answer (score 0):

> Stringify your data like this so you will not have to worry about putting quotes around paramter name and its value.

```
JSON.stringify({ data:data})
```